# Initial data for Flask/Sqlalchemy

Tags: sql, database, flask

Is there a tool for loading initial data (and dumping data out to json) for flask with sqlalchemy ORM? Something similar to django's loaddata and dumpdata.

Answer (score 5):

No, there's not. You have to use the tools of the used database. Especially PostgreSQLs utilities for this are very versatile, much more than Django's.

However, If your real question is just "How do I get some initial data into the database", e.g. while developing, then you can do something like this:

```
def init_db():
    if db_session.query(User).count() == 0:
        admin = User("admin", "admin")
        db_session.add(admin)
        db_session.commit()
```